# Visual Studio ReportViewer repeating data block on every page

Tags: visual-studio, reportviewer

I am using Reportviewer to generate a sales invoice to be printed by the user. How can I get databound fields to be printed on every page of a multi page invoice?

The invoice is printed on a pre-printed form. I want the printed form to look roughly like:

page 1
customer john smith
123 main st.
city, CA 90000

some item1 $100
some item2 $150
some item3 $150

page 2
customer john smith
123 main st.
city, CA 90000

some item4 $500
some item5 $250
some item6 $950
Total $2100

Using 1 list which contains databound textbox fields for the customer info, and a table for the items. The problem is if there are many items such that the items flow over to page 2, the next page only contains items, and not the customer info which needs to be printed on second page as well.

I tried using page header, but I can't use databound items in page header. Please Help!

Answer (score 3):

Open the RDLC document in XML view. Locate the block of code just beneath the TablixColumnHierarchy tree and modify like this appropriately. The key is setting RepeatOnNewPage tag = true between the TablixMember tag.

Hope this prevents hours of battling with this for other people!

See snippets below:

```
    ... 
    <TablixColumnHierarchy>
      <TablixMembers>
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
        <TablixMember />
      </TablixMembers>
    </TablixColumnHierarchy>
    <TablixRowHierarchy>
      <TablixMembers>
        <TablixMember>
          <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
          <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
        </TablixMember>
        <TablixMember>
          <KeepWithGroup>After</KeepWithGroup>
          <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
        </TablixMember>
        <TablixMember>
          <Group Name="Details" />
          <RepeatOnNewPage>true</RepeatOnNewPage>
        </TablixMember>
      </TablixMembers>
    </TablixRowHierarchy>
    <RepeatColumnHeaders>true</RepeatColumnHeaders>
    <RepeatRowHeaders>true</RepeatRowHeaders>
    <FixedColumnHeaders>true</FixedColumnHeaders>
    <FixedRowHeaders>true</FixedRowHeaders>
    <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
    <DataSetName>ds_Triangulation</DataSetName>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

i presume you use Table in the report body just add grouping by item and in the group header put the customer info and just set RepeatOnNewPage to treu for the report header row
Best Regards,
Iordan

Answer (score 0):

A highly valuable resource is the [GotReportViewer](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/) site, they have a sample there called Invoice Maker which is worth a look.

A trick you can use is described on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252093%28VS.80%29.aspx), it involves adding the fields you want in the Page Header to the body of your report, then hiding the field, then in your Page Header referring to the hidden text field, e.g. =First(ReportItems!txtHiddenFieldName.Value)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked out the invoice maker sample project, it basically works the same was as mine. When I added a lot of items, page 2 shows only items. 

I'll check out the MSDN page, sounds like what I need.

Comment: The GotReportViewer site is a good general resource for Report Viewer information, the MSDN page article shows how to solve your actual problem.